# Is there a command that includes files in a project of Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm developing a web project that consists from many other projects, so
when I build my main project I need to copy some resource files to the folder of main project
and make all copied files as included in this project.

I'm using post event feature for doing this.

```
xcopy /E /Y  "SourcePath1" "$(ProjectDir)Scripts\"
xcopy /E /Y  "SourcePath2" "$(ProjectDir)Scripts\"
xcopy /E /Y  "SourcePath3" "$(ProjectDir)Scripts\"
```

this command copies my files, but these files are not included in the project. What command can I use for including copied files?

I need something like

```
include "pathtwherefilesare"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can the inclusion be done on the commandline? For example when the files copied are not always the identical numbers but grow over time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can copy once, and add copied files to project, then commands will replace old files with new ones

Hope this helps

Comment: yes, i'm doing as you said now, but if there is a new file I need to include it by myself each time.

Answer (score 1):

There is a icon in the solution explorer to "show all files". Then you can include (right click) these files to your project.

Comment: no, I need a command that will executed automaticly by after build event

Comment: If you do this one time, then you shouldn't do that each time. The next times the files will be overwritten, but they are already included in your project.

Comment: yes, but if a new file will appear I need to include it by myself again

Comment: Is there the possibility to simply add the projects with the resources to your other project?

Answer (score 0):

If your project is a web application project (as opposed to web site project), try `Add Existing Items`, select the files, and select `Add as Link` from the Add button dropdown menu.

Edit the files' `Build Action` and `Copy to Output Directory` settings as required.

Comment: no, Output directory is a bin directory. I need to copy my files in another places